# Define left join conditions when using .includes in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to find the best way to include a referenced model on what is essentially a compound key.

I have `ChecklistItem` (a list of things to do daily) and then `ChecklistChecks` (which ties the `ChecklistItem` together with a `User` for a particular day. These checklists can either be for all `Stores` (with a null `store_id`) or for a particular `Store`.

This pulls all of the `ChecklistItems` and their associated checks:

```
ChecklistItem.includes(:checklist_checks).where(store_id: [nil,@store.id], list_type: 'open')
```

The problem is that there would be checks from multiple days in there. What I need is to pull all of the `ChecklistItems` and any checks from a specific day.

I tried adding conditions like this:

```
ChecklistItem.includes(:checklist_checks).where(store_id: [nil,@store.id], list_type: 'open', checklist_checks: {store_id: @store.id, report_date: @today})
```

The problem is that will only pull `ChecklistItems` that have an associated `ChecklistCheck`.

It is generating SQL that is essentially:

```
SELECT 
    checklist_items.*,
    checklist_checks.* 
FROM 
    checklist_items 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    checklist_checks 
ON 
    checklist_checks.checklist_item_id = checklist_items.id 
WHERE 
    checklist_items.list_type = 'open' 
AND 
    checklist_checks.store_id = 1 
AND 
    checklist_checks.report_date = '2015-05-03' 
AND 
    (checklist_items.store_id = 1 OR checklist_items.store_id IS NULL)
```

I think the problem is that the conditions on `checklist_checks` is in the WHERE clause. If I could move them to the ON clause of the join, everything would work.

Is there a Rails way to end up with something like this?

```
SELECT 
    checklist_items.*,
    checklist_checks.* 
FROM 
    checklist_items 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    checklist_checks 
ON 
    checklist_checks.checklist_item_id = checklist_items.id 
AND 
    checklist_checks.store_id = 1 
AND 
    checklist_checks.report_date = '2015-05-03' 
WHERE 
    checklist_items.list_type = 'open' 
AND 
    (checklist_items.store_id = 1 OR checklist_items.store_id IS NULL)
```

**UPDATE:**
I found this: [enter link description here](http://cha1tanya.com/2013/10/26/preload-associations-with-find-by-sql.html)
It suggests using `find_by_sql` and then passing the result array and model to be included to `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload`

I tried that, and my `find_by_sql` pulls the right stuff, but the `id` column is nil in the resulting objects.

```
@store = Store.find(1)
@today = Date.today - 1.days
@open_items = ChecklistItem.find_by_sql(["SELECT checklist_items.*, checklist_checks.* FROM checklist_items LEFT OUTER JOIN checklist_checks ON checklist_checks.checklist_item_id = checklist_items.id AND checklist_checks.store_id = ? AND checklist_checks.report_date = ? WHERE checklist_items.list_type='open' AND (checklist_items.store_id=? OR checklist_items.store_ID IS NULL)", @store.id, @today, @store_id])
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(@open_items, :checklist_checks)

> @open_items.first.name
=> "Turn on the lights"
> @open_items.first.id
=> nil
```

Comment: You could use `.joins` with a custom sql fragment.

Comment: I tried that too. For some reason custom SQL in joins doesn't allow parameters. I could hard code the parameters, but think I found a solution.

Comment: Nope. False alarm on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) to generate a custom join clause:

```
class ChecklistItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :checklist_checks


  # ...

  def self.superjoin(date, store_id)

    # build the ON clause for the join
    on = Arel::Nodes::On.new(
      Arel::Nodes::Equality.new(ChecklistChecks.arel_table[:checklist_item_id], ChecklistItem.arel_table[:id]).\
      and(ChecklistItem.arel_table[:store_id].eq(1)).\
      and(ChecklistChecks.arel_table[:report_date].eq(date))
    )
    joins(Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin.new(ChecklistChecks.arel_table, on))
      .where(store_id: [nil, store_id], list_type: 'open' )
  end
end
```

I bundled it up into a model method to make it easier to test in the rails console.

```
irb(main):117:0> ChecklistItem.superjoin(1,2)
  ChecklistItem Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "checklist_items".* FROM "checklist_items" LEFT OUTER JOIN "checklist_checks" ON "checklist_checks"."checklist_item_id" = "checklist_items"."id" AND "checklist_items"."store_id" = 1 AND "checklist_checks"."report_date" = 1 WHERE (("checklist_items"."store_id" = 2 OR "checklist_items"."store_id" IS NULL)) AND "checklist_items"."list_type" = 'open'
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```